# How to add finded path to new graph in Neo4j Browser?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I find the area having fixed size around definded node.

```
MATCH path = (n:A {title:"WATER"})-[r*2]-(m:B)
RETURN path
```

I need to write finded area like new graph.
There is a simple way to do it? Something like `MERGE path`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do ... you want to rewrite the found path in the database ?

Comment: Yes, I need to create a new label and write founded path there.
Generaly, my task is to create copy of graph's part.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
MATCH path = (n:A {title:"WATER"})-[r*2]-(m:B)

WITH path UNWIND NODES(path) AS node
    MERGE (n:NewNode {id:id(node)})
WITH path UNWIND RELS(path) AS rel
    MERGE (s:NewNode {id:id(startNode(rel))})
    MERGE (e:NewNode {id:id(endNode(rel))})
    MERGE (s)-[:NEW_REL]->(e)
```